# Program to track time and describe what I did

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I want to know if there is any program to run like this app of `chrome` extension [Simple Time Track](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-time-track/hbhcgdpbdenjjpekdajanfgchlgacdea).

Because I want to count the time that I spend in a task.

I´m using `Windows 8.1`, but also can be app to use with `Chrome`.

Comment: Have you tried Rescue Time? https://www.rescuetime.com

Comment: no, i´m gonna try

Comment: It didn´t worked as I wanted.